# Recovering the contacts, sms and call log from sd card - android

Tags: android, contacts, restore

I am using an android phone running on version 2.3.5. Its a micromax A57 phone. Since there was a problem in the launcher, I reset the phone to factory settings taking my sd card out. Since the phone's internal memory is very less, all the contacts, call log and sms are saved in the sd card. While doing factory reset, my assumption was to restore it back from the sd card. But when inserted the sd card back, phone could not get any of my contact, sms and call log. I searched over internet for past 2 days and tried several applications to get it back but all in vain. My questions are,

1. First of all, would it be possible to get the sms, contact and call log back from sd card (as I reset mobile alone taking sd card out)?
2. If possible, how to restore sms, contact and call log.

Phone is rooted and I am sure the data lies somewhere in the phone as bits and bytes. Experts advise please.

Comment: This question is not related to programming. Please consider asking on [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com/). You might get an answer there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an android phone and not development please try http://android.stackexchange.com (not OT for super user)

Comment: Thanks guys, moved this question android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my knowledge call logs app and  sms app store the data within the application as you have reset your phone this means every system app data is cleared hence all contacts and sms had been washed out.
only chance you have taken the backup your data manually , so it might be a possibility your data is stored in sd card